# Wrapping multiple Iterables into a single Interable

Tags: java, collections

Say I have two `Collections`:

```
Collection< Integer > foo = new ArrayList< Integer >();
Collection< Integer > bar = new ArrayList< Integer >();
```

and say sometimes I would like to iterate over them individually, but sometimes together. Is there a way to create a wrapper around `foo` and `bar` so that I can iterate over the combined pair, but which is also updated whenever `foo` and `bar` change? (i.e. `Collection.addAll()` is not suitable).

For example:

```
Collection< Integer > wrapper = ... // holds references to both bar and foo

foo.add( 1 );
bar.add( 99 );

for( Integer fooInt : foo ) {
    System.out.println( fooInt );
} // output: 1

for( Integer barInt : bar ) {
    System.out.println( barInt );
} // output: 99

for( Integer wrapInt : wrapper ) {
    System.out.println( wrapInt );
} // output: 1, 99

foo.add( 543 );

for( Integer wrapInt : wrapper ) {
    System.out.println( wrapInt );
} // output: 1, 99, 543
```

Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to say, unfortunately I'm unable to access any libraries other than the stock Java libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote two functions for that :

```
/**
 * Create an Iterator from multiple Iterators. The returned Iterator
 * traverses all elements from all sources, in the order, as if they belong
 * to the same source.
 * 
 * @param <T> type of elements
 * @param sources sources of the elements, in order of traversal
 * @return an iterator over multiple iterators in sequence
 */
public static <T> Iterator<T> concatenate(final Iterator<T> ... sources) {
    if (sources.length == 0) {
        return new Iterator<T>() {
            @Override public boolean hasNext() { return false; }
            @Override public T next() { throw new NoSuchElementException("end of iteration"); }
            @Override public void remove() { throw new IllegalStateException("no previous element"); }
        };
    }
    return new Iterator<T>() {

        Iterator<Iterator<T>> sourcesIterator = Arrays.asList(sources).iterator();
        Iterator<T> currentIterator = sourcesIterator.next();

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (currentIterator.hasNext()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                if (sourcesIterator.hasNext()) {
                    currentIterator = sourcesIterator.next();
                    return hasNext();
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if (hasNext()) {
                return currentIterator.next();
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("end of iteration");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            currentIterator.remove();
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Create an Iterable from multiple Iterables. The returned Iterable
 * traverses all elements from all sources, in the order, as if they belong
 * to the same source.
 * 
 * @param <T> type of elements
 * @param sources sources of the elements, in order of traversal
 * @return an iterable over multiple iterators in sequence
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // impossible to create a generic array
public static <T> Iterable<T> concatenate(final Iterable<T> ... sources) {
    return new Iterable<T>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            final Iterator[] iteratorsArrays = new Iterator[sources.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
                iteratorsArrays[i] = sources[i].iterator();
            }
            return concatenate(iteratorsArrays);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: The main issue I see with this compared to Guava's approach is that it eagerly retrieves all the iterators for the source iterables when `iterator()` is called on the concatenated `Iterable`, whereas Guava only retrieves each iterator as it's actually needed. I imagine this wouldn't be much of an issue in most cases, but it does extend the lifetime of the iterators.

Comment: @ColinD : you are right. This is by design, but clearly there are cases where lazy creation of iterators is desired.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Iterables.concat](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) methods.

```
Iterable<Integer> wrapped = Iterables.concat(foo, bar);
```

Comment: Like the look of it, but unfortunately not an option for me: I'm unable to use any libraries other than what I've already got.

Comment: @Dunnie: That's too bad. You could look at the code to see how to write your own. It's pretty similar to what @barjak suggests.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? I answered this before the libraries thing was mentioned, and this is still probably the best reference there is for doing this sort of thing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/index.html) - CollectionUtils or IteratorUtils. The have the type of methods you are looking for.

Comment: As for ColinD's answer: I'm unable to use any libraries other than what I've already got.

Comment: Ah, you gotta love companies that make you reinvent the wheel. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A simple List of List isn't that much boilerplate:

```
List <List <Integer>> metalist = new ArrayList <List <Integer>> ();
metalist.add (foo);
metalist.add (bar);
for (List<Integer> list : metalist) 
    for (Integer wrapInt : list)
        System.out.println (wrapInt);
```

If you now add 4 to foo `foo.add (4);` you just repeat the 2 loops. Where is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Like @barjak, but shorter

```
public static <E> Collection<E> concat(Collection<E> ... es) {
    List<E> ret = new ArrayList<E>();
    for (Collection<E> e : es) ret.addAll(e);
    return ret;
}

public static <E> Iterable<E> viewOf(final Collection<E> ... es) {
    return new Iterable<E>() {
        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return concat(es).iterator();
        }
    };
}

Collection< Integer > foo = new ArrayList< Integer >();
Collection< Integer > bar = new ArrayList< Integer >();

// call as often as you like.
for(Integer i : concat(foo, bar))

// OR
Iterable<Integer> view = viewOf(foo, bar);

// call as often as you like.
for(Integer i : view)
```

Comment: This doesn't do what was asked. The result needs to be a view of the underlying iterables.

Comment: @ColinD, now it is.  It depends on how it is called.  The difference is symantic IMHO.

Comment: That's closer, but still does copying which is unnecessary and wastes time and memory.

Comment: @ColinD, Possibly less than you can measure in the real application, however I can measure a waste of developer time and possible introduction of bugs in a more complex answer. ;)

Comment: If performance was a real issue you wouldn't use List&lt;Integer>, you would use something like TIntArrayList or plain int[].

Comment: This is a general purpose method, not just for use with `Integer`. I imagine that's just an example. And you shouldn't intentionally sacrifice performance just because you aren't using the most bleeding edge performant structure. The difference in usability between arrays and collections is extreme. I agree with you about developer time (which is why I suggested a library), but there isn't really any advantage in copy/pasting this code vs. @barjak's, say.